# Send image stream byte data flutter to native Android

Tags: android, flutter, dart, image-processing, google-mlkit

I was trying to process the live camera feed from flutter so I needed to send the byte data to nativve Android for processing.

I was concatenating the 3 planes as suggested by [flutterfire](https://github.com/FirebaseExtended/flutterfire/blob/8ddab6870ff46b55f212b335eed726d7575cd1d3/packages/firebase_ml_vision/lib/src/firebase_vision.dart#L149). I needed the data to create an [InputImage](https://developers.google.com/ml-kit/vision/pose-detection/android#using-a-bytebuffer-or-bytearray) for the google ml kit.

Concatenate Plane method

```
static Uint8List _concatenatePlanes(List<Plane> planes) {
    final WriteBuffer allBytes = WriteBuffer();
    for (Plane plane in planes) {
      allBytes.putUint8List(plane.bytes);
    }
    return allBytes.done().buffer.asUint8List();
  }
```

Input Image created from the image data in native Android

```
public void fromByteBuffer(Map<String, Object> imageData, final MethodChannel.Result result) {
  byte[] bytes = (byte[]) imageData.get("bytes");

  int rotationCompensation = ((int) imageData.get("rotation")) % 360;

//Create an input image
  InputImage inputImage = InputImage.fromByteArray(bytes,
                (int) imageData.get("width"),
                (int) imageData.get("height"),
                 rotationCompensation,
                InputImage.IMAGE_FORMAT_NV21);
}
```

I am not getting any results after processing a frame from camera stream, but if the same frame is captured, stored and then processed by creating the Input Image from file path the image is being processed properly.

Is there anything wrong in the way I am creating the input image.
Any help is appreciated.

Comment: The camera streaming use case has been working fine with the native code on Android. I am wondering it is related to how the rotationDegree is calculated. Could you refer to this[1] link to see if you can do the same for computing a correct rotationDegree?

[1]https://github.com/googlesamples/mlkit/blob/3f41503f4e917129039391d3d4096da6bfa75673/android/vision-quickstart/app/src/main/java/com/google/mlkit/vision/demo/CameraSource.java#L524

Comment: Thank you @ChenxiSong I'll try this and let you know the results.

Comment: Hi, the ML Kit InputImage you are using does support android.media.Image as an input. https://developers.google.com/ml-kit/vision/pose-detection/android?hl=en#using-a-media.image. When building your flutter plugin, could you pass that directly through the method channel?

Comment: Hi @ChenxiSong Yeah I am already using that method and it is working fine. But we also need to process the camera stream data to get live information. I tried your above suggestion for live detection unfortunately it did not give any results. If you come up with any other solution let me know. Thanks

Comment: I see. Since the android native sdk has been working fine. I guess it is related to how flutter works. Sorry for not being able to help further.

Comment: Thanks for the help anyways.

Comment: @Mr.Despicable I have same scenario, for me native android is lagging a lot. Did you end up solving this issue?